# PRESTASHOP How to check/get order status by API

Tags: api, prestashop

I need to check order status of order I created. I have API key and order number.

Can I check by API if order status were changed? I.e. admin change status of an order to: shipped. Can I (using API) get an information that status was chenged?

I need to check order status from external site.

External site <---check status od an order---> Shop

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods:

1. Use webservice api, I had used PSWebServiceLibrary,

   where I used to send resource = 'order' and id =  and it will give result of whole order including status.
2. Second is, create a hook in prestashop and send status & orderid to your server via CURL and update your DB accordingly.